# Domain of $f(x,y)=\sqrt {x}\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{xy}$

Tags: functions, soft-question

Given that we have the following equality $f(x,y)=\sqrt {x}\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{xy}$, does the domain of a function depends on how I write it?

So what is the domain of  $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$? And what is the domain of  $f(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when does product of two numbers positive ($0$ is included)

Comment: I can't understand your observation. Please could you make it clearer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ to make sense we need "both" ${x,y}$ to be positive($0$ included).

for $\sqrt{xy}$ we need $xy$ to be positive which does not necessarily require $x$ "and " $y$ to be positive.

what does this say about your domain?

Make sure that $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ may not even make sense even if $\sqrt{xy}$ makes sense.

Please be careful on that part.

Comment: Nice explanation :-)

Answer (score 3):

The domain of $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ is different from the domain of  $\sqrt{xy}$. In fact, for the first function $$\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+\cup(0,0)$$ is its domain but for the other $$\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+\cup \mathbb R^-\times\mathbb R^-\cup(0,0)$$

Answer (score 2):

for $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$, we need $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$, so the domain is the first quadrant with two axis.

for $f(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$, we need $xy\ge0$, so the domain is the first and third quadrant with two axis.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $\sqrt x\sqrt y$ is "$x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$".

On the other hand, the domain of $\sqrt{xy}$ is $xy\ge0$, so...

Note that the two are different.

Comment: @B.S So the domain of a function could depend on how I write it? Or those functions are not the same?

Comment: They are different functions. Do you understand why? You can consider the graph. For example, the first funtion is not defined at $(x,y)=(1,1)$, but the second function is defined at the point.

Comment: Looking at the graph I can clearly understand the point, yes. The strange thing is that these two functions are algebraically the same but they are different functions... Am I right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. They are not the same even algebraically. Note that $\sqrt{xy}\not=\sqrt{x}\sqrt y$. You'll see the reason if you think of $(x,y)=(-1,-1).$